# Conditionally instantiating classes that use @Inject

Tags: java, guice

I'm trying to understand how to handle conditionally creating new instances of a class that uses @Inject. In the below example I have a factory that instantiates classes based on a parameter.

`AnimalFactory`  does not have access to the `injector` the main class of my application has, so I can't use `injector.getInstance(Cat.class)`

```
class AnimalFactory {

    public IAnimal create(AnimalType type) {
        if (type.equals(AnimalType.CAT)) {
            return new Cat(); // Cat uses @Inject, so this won't work of course. But ???
        } else if (type.equals(AnimalType.DOG)) {
            return new Dog(); 
        }
    }
}
```

In the rest of my app, classes are injected into my constructors because I always need them. Guice creates an instance/singleton for each. But in this scenario, I do **not** want to create and inject instances for each animal because all but one are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a MapBinder as described [here](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Multibindings#mapbinder):

```
public class AnimalModule extends AbstractModule {
  public void configure() {
    MapBinder<AnimalType, IAnimal> animalBinder= MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), AnimalType.class, IAnimal.class);

    animalBinder.addBinding(AnimalType.DOG).to(Dog.class);
     ...
  }
}
```

And than use it in your factory:

```
class AnimalFactory {
   @Inject
   Map<AnimalType, IAnimal> animals;

   public IAnimal create(AnimalType type) {
       return animals.get(type);
   }
 }
```

Comment: After posting I dug around for a while and found this as a possible solution. This is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I worked on exactly the same issue and I wrote a feature that allows you to create self-populating factory. Meaning that if you work in Spring/Spring-boot environment you can create a factory that can access and provide any interface implementing class that is managed by Spring-boot without injecting in the factory. You can also give the instances custom names. So, it seems like it fits your case exactly. Here is a link to an article that describes the feature in great detail: [Non-intrusive access to "Orphaned" Beans in Spring framework](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/non-intrusive-access-orphaned-beans-spring-framework-michael-gantman/). Also, in MgntUtils library Javadoc there is a good description of the feature here [enter link description here](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/package-summary.html). The library itself including source code could be found on Github [here](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) and in the package `com.mgnt.lifecycle.management.example` there is a working example. Maven artifacts are [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils)